# pip install greenletでFailed building wheel for greenletエラー

Tags: python

python初心者です。

pip install でgreenlet をインストールできずに困っています。
下記エラーがでてしまいます、原因と対策を教えていただきたいです。

easy_installも試してみましたが、インストールできませんでした。

```
➜  ~  pip install greenlet                             
Collecting greenlet
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.7.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for greenlet
  Complete output from command /Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-build-GCkMtj/greenlet/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/tmphSDIhipip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'greenlet' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
  clang -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
  clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.so
  ld: file not found: python.exe
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: greenlet
  Running setup.py install for greenlet
    Complete output from command /Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-build-GCkMtj/greenlet/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-Xcoq_M-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
    clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.so
    ld: file not found: python.exe
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/user01/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-build-GCkMtj/greenlet/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-Xcoq_M-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/h6/3g536yxn74v8rclc67008gb00000gn/T/pip-build-GCkMtj/greenlet
➜  ~
```

Comment: 同じ様な問題が報告されていました。[Unable to install compiled Python modules under pyenv on OS X 10.10](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/273) Python 2.7.8 で fix された様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Python のバージョンアップで無事に解決しました。

Comment: @shuucream2011 本質問が解決したことを他のユーザに分かりやすくするため、お手数ですがご自身で回答を記入し、承認して頂ければと思います。